# Serving images from public folder loads onetime and shows 404 when i refresh again in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, production-environment, dalli, engineyard

Image is present in the server but i get the message the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
but when i copy the url and put in browser i get the image,but the same url i refresh i get 404.
I don't know what is the issue it happens only in the server environment,It works fine in the local environment

My app is deployed in the engine yard,using memcache dalli server

Solutions tried:
   I had set config.serve_static_assets = true but i doesn't gave any solution.
   I had checked the image file format,its jpeg format and data is in binary format. 
   public image folder is given with full permission too.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Live Compilation,

> config.assets.compile = true